# How to set 'Fit all columns on one page' in print tab

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

The only thing I would want is to always set the 'Fit all columns on one page' setting when users open the Print tab in Excel.

And no, they don't want to do it themselves. What a surprise :)

Here is a screenshot of where that is in Excel 2013:[image]

Tried to look for some VBA code like the following but without success.

`With Sheets("Print Letter").PageSetup
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
End With`

Comment: Are you looking for **SetPrintArea**??

Comment: For Office-JS API see --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917355/set-fit-all-columns-on-one-page-via-excel-javascript-api

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try setting the `.FitToPagesTall` to `False` to be able to manually set the `.FitToPagesWide` property.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup.fittopagestall(v=office.15).aspx)

> If this property is False, Microsoft Excel scales the worksheet
>   according to the FitToPagesWide property. If the Zoom property is
>   True, the FitToPagesTall property is ignored.

```
Sub PrintColumns()
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With Sheets("Print Letter").PageSetup
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Should I then add `.Zoom = False` just in case so it never ignores the FitToPagesTall property?

Comment: I just added ´Application.PrintCommunication = False´ to my code and that did the trick!

Comment: .Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False is working fine thanks.