# How can it set the file for "Fit all columns on one page" setting

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a requirement where files generated by Apache POI need to produce a fie with the [fit all columns on one page setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741049/how-to-set-fit-all-columns-on-one-page-in-print-tab-of-excel-2013) set. I've tried a bunch of variations with the API but so far I haven't been able to do it. Nor can I really find if it can be done.

It seems like the `setFitToPage(true)` function resizes both the height and width not just the width like I want. Using `setFitWidth` and `setFitHeight` like I find in various other stack overflow questions doesn't seem to affect anything.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public void setPrintSettings(Sheet sheet) {

   sheet.setFitToPage(true); //this will resize both height and width to fit
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);

   sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short) 1);
   sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short) 1);

}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in Apache POI but maybe this helps you https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201308.mbox/%3C1375955582.58916.YahooMailNeo@web122301.mail.ne1.yahoo.com%3E

Comment: That is it too, RubioRic. Thanks, why did I not find that right away?

Comment: roytuts.com/fit-excel-sheet-to-one-page-using-apache-poi-in-java/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not the call to `setFitToPage(true)` that makes Excel resize both the height and width to fit one page.  This call is necessary, but for a different reason.  In Excel's Page Setup screen, this method call controls which radio button is active in the dialog box.  The value `true` sets the radio button for "Fit to:", allowing you to control the page(s) wide by page(s) tall boxes.  The value `false` sets the radio button for "Adjust to: ", percentage normal size.

In this case, you want to fit it to 1 page wide by "don't care" pages tall.  The value to use for pages tall (`setFitHeight` method) is `0` here.

```
sheet.setFitToPage(true);
PrintSetup ps = sheet.getPrintSetup();
ps.setFitWidth( (short) 1);
ps.setFitHeight( (short) 0);
```

When I write out a `Workbook` containing a `Sheet` with these settings, and I open it in Excel, the Page Setup dialog box has the "Fit to:" radio button selected, and "1 page(s) wide by (blank) tall".  In the "Print Preview" screen, the print settings options lists "Fit All Columns on One Page" as selected.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to add `sheet.setAutobreaks(true);` for the sheet to switch to the "Fit to" Scaling option.

Comment: For me `ps.setFitWidth( (short) 1);` `ps.setFitHeight( (short) 1);` what was worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ExportPartsToExcel(this System.Data.DataTable DataTable, string ExcelFilePath = null)
    {
        int ColumnsCount;
        int RowShift = 7;

        ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count;

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        Application Excel = new Application();
        Excel.Workbooks.Add();

        // single worksheet
        _Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Sheets[1].Name = "TEST";

        Excel.PrintCommunication = false; //This has to be set, or FittoPagesWide crashes
        Worksheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = true;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.5;
        Excel.PrintCommunication = true;

        // check fielpath
        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
        {
            Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
            Excel.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Worksheet);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(TitleRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(HeaderRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(CellRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Excel);
        }
        else
        // no filepath is given
        {
            Excel.Visible = true;
        }
```

This works for me, basically I've set both         `Worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = true;` and `Worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;`