# Set 'Fit All Columns on One Page' via Excel JavaScript API

Tags: excel, printing, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm looking to set the "Fit All Columns on Page" print option via the Excel JavaScript API. It's very similar to this question which uses VBA -->

[How to set 'Fit all columns on one page' in print tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741049/how-to-set-fit-all-columns-on-one-page-in-print-tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office 365 Online Automate Scripts helped get me on the right path.

Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagelayoutzoomoptions?view=excel-js-preview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagelayout?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-pagelayout-zoom-member

Code:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var PageLayoutZoomOptions_Obj = {
        'horizontalFitToPages': 1,
        'verticalFitToPages': 0,
    }
    ws.pageLayout.zoom = PageLayoutZoomOptions_Obj
    await context.sync();
});
```

Note: I had issues using/including `scale` so I just left it out.